# Switching multiple databases on each request in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application

I need to write a console application in C# .net core. This console application should subscribe to an event hub. It listens to the events hubs and when it receives a message through event hub , it reads the message and processes it. The message contains customer Id and some other information needed for processing the data.

In the database, we have created database for each customer. Database name is equal to customer Id. Now the C# service needs to connect to database dynamically based on the customer id received in the message.

I'm using Entity framework to write the code.

I have done a similar work in web API using DBConext in startup.cs like below:

```
 services.AddDbContext<CustomerContext>(options =>
            {
                var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                var httpRouteData = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.GetRouteData();
                var db = httpRouteData?.Values["customerId"]?.ToString();
                db = db?.Replace('-', '_');
                options.UseNpgsql(
                        new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
                        {
                            Host = "Hostname",
                            Port = "port",
                            SslMode = SslMode.Require,
                            Username = "username",
                            Database = db,
                            Password = "password",
                            Timeout = 1024,
                            CommandTimeout = 60000
                        }.ConnectionString
                    );
            });
```

So every request, based on the customerId in the httpcontext route data, we were able to form the connection string dynamically. And used this DBContext via dependency injection. How can this feature be achieved in a console application?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to get dbcontext connectionstring each time for a customer.

```
  public class CustomerContextFactory : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, CustomerContext> _dbContexts = new Dictionary<string, CustomerContext>();

    public CustomerContext GetContext(string customerId)
    {
        if (!_dbContexts.TryGetValue(customerId, out var context))
        {
            var connectionString = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                Host = "Hostname",
                Port = "port",
                SslMode = SslMode.Require,
                Username = "username",
                Database = customerId.Replace('-', '_'),
                Password = "password",
                Timeout = 1024,
                CommandTimeout = 60000
            }.ConnectionString;

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CustomerContext>()
                .UseNpgsql(connectionString);

            context = new CustomerContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
            _dbContexts.Add(customerId, context);
        }

        return context;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var context in _dbContexts.Values)
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

use it to get the DbContext instance for the customer ID in the message:

```
void HandleEvent(EventData eventData)
{
    var customerId = eventData.Properties["CustomerId"].ToString();
    using (var contextFactory = new CustomerContextFactory())
    using (var context = contextFactory.GetContext(customerId))
    {
        // Use the context to process the message
        // ...
    }
}
```